# How to approach a Spinner + "add new item" button + selectable items

Tags: android, layout, spinner, android-arrayadapter, dropdown

First, I want to create a spinner with a drop-down menu that has an extra "add new item" button. Second, I want each item (besides the button) to be highlight-able upon long click (so I could delete them via delete icon). I could not make it pass my first problem.

**Attempt 1:** I tried modifying ArrayAdapter's getCount() to add +1 & modifying getDropDownView() to return a different view for the last item. I got an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

**Attempt 2:** I also tried to add a "null" item that I would then convert within getDropDownView() but I got a NullPointerException as the ArrayAdapter's internal code was calling toString() on the null item.

My second problem adds even more layers of complexity as it would make the dropdown menu multimodal. I'm thinking I shouldn't base this on the Spinner class, but I still want it to work like a Spinner. How should I approach this?

Comment: you can use custom view rather than spinner.so you can achieve all thing what you want.

Answer (score 1):

For the "add new item" button, you can create a custom adapter which wraps a regular ArrayAdapter and also adds the functionality for the button.